# 404 error on Craft homepage

Tags: error-message, 404

I'm having some trouble on a fresh install of Craft. I've uploaded all the files to my server and moved `index.php` (etc) out of the `public` folder and into the root directory.

I've also changed `index.php`'s `$craftPath` to this:

```
$craftPath = './craft';
```

But I'm still getting a 404 error on the homepage. I've set permissions on the folders, but still nothing.

My file structure looks like this:

[image: FTP]

Any suggestions..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contacted my host and for some reason PHP was not enabled as default on my account. This solved the problem.

Comment: Yup, that would do it! Well done Chrish :)

Answer (score 2):

Change this:

```
$craftPath = './craft';
```

to this:

```
$craftPath = 'craft';
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't do it, still getting the same error. `404 - File or directory not found.`

Comment: Not sure if it's helpful but `/admin` doesn't work either